# To keep from (phrase-translation)

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

Kiel oni diras "to keep from" kun la senco malebligi ke oni faru ion? "I can't keep you from making bad choices." ĉu preventi?

Answer (score 6):

> I can't keep you from making bad choices.

Mi ne povas **deteni vin de** malbonaj elektoj.

> My father's stories kept me from drinking alcohol.

Historioj de mia patro **detenis min de** alkoholtrinkado.

Comment: Dankon al vi ĉiuj! Mi disponas nun kelkajn bonajn manierojn por esprimi tion. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ŝajnas al mi ke vi respondis la propran demandon.

- malebligi ke oni faru ion
- malebligi al iu faru ion

Comment: What about the cases where you are kept from doing something, that you are still able of doing? "My father's stories kept me from drinking alcohol, even though I wanted to try, like all my friends did." I don't think the sense here is that the stories made it impossible for the person to drink. Instead, they caused a certain desicion.

Comment: "My father's stories kept me from drinking alcohol" - Mi ne trinkis, pro rakontoj el mia patro.

Comment: Pro la historioj de mia patro...

Comment: "La rakontoj de mia patro instigis min ne drinki".

Answer (score 0):

This is from Duolingo:

> La malbona vetero malebligis al ni labori.

Comment: "Halti" ne estas transitiva.  La tri supraj frazoj estas malĝustaj.

Comment: @Lee Vi pravas kaj dankon

Comment: This answer has been edited but there are still some issues with it. It would be better to say *malhelpi al iu* -- but that doesn't mean quite the same thing as keeping someone from doing something. It only means that doing it would become more difficult.

Comment: At the time I'm leaving this comment, it looks like this answer has been edited again. It's standing at -1, and in the current version looks essentially the same as my own answer, so I suppose I should vote it up (to 0).